# Unable to load dynamic library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have uploaded a CodeIgniter application on server and getting this error, application is working perfectly in local server

[image]

After searching around stackoverflow I found that It may be an extension issue. 
But don't know how to solve this extension issue on live server ?

Comment: uncomment the line imagick.so in php.ini file

Comment: install the extension by this way "yum install php-imagick.so"

Comment: I dont have permission to edit php.ini file, Is there any other way to set php.ini for your codeigniter application only

Comment: I changed the environment of codeigniter to production and my issue solved. I know its not the right way, but for now everything is working fine

Comment: The issue is probably there, changing environment in codeigniter only disable error messages

Answer (score 1):

In index.php file of CI I have changed environment from development to production

```
$_SERVER['CI_ENV'] = 'production'; // By Adding this line
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```